# Hooking action once but called twice

Tags: widgets, actions, init

```
class GridModSidebars{
public function init(){
    add_action('widgets_init', array($this, 'registerSidebars'),20);
}

public function registerSidebars(){
    $args = array(
        'name'          => __('Page Middle Sidebar %d', APP_TD),
            'id'            => 'page-middle-sidebar',          
        'description'   => __('This sidebar is used to place the add in page content above and below', APP_TD),
        'class'         => '',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>' );
    register_sidebars(2, $args);        
}
}
```

I have this code.

'registerSidebars' funciton is called twice and with this code total4 sidebar get registered. How ever the init action is called once.

I have checked with echo.Can anyone help about this?

Ad I have searched with 'registerSidebars' and it only found twice one for while adding the hook, and another time while function declaration..

Comment: I would start with dumping [`wp_debug_backtrace_summary()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_debug_backtrace_summary/).

Comment: You havent shown us how you call your GridModSidebars class.

Comment: The GridModSidebars class init function is called from the theme functions.php at the very begining with any hook.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this?

Comment: @SeanKendle, it's long back, the obvious technical reason was class init method was called twice